# Reading and merging specific columns from two different files

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read specific lines in the third columns of two different files and merge them into a file with two columns. Specifically: I want to read line 9 – (17+2*139) from file 1 and line (17+2*139) – end from file 2. Below is the code that I wrote. It only outputs the result from the first file:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream outfile_LD("outfile_LD.dat");
    std::ifstream outfile_LE("outfile_LE.dat");

    std::string line_LD;
    std::string line_LE;
    int count = 0;
    if (!outfile_LD || !outfile_LE) {
        std::cout << "Error opening file" <<
                     (outfile_LD? 2: 1) << ": " <<
                     strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (outfile_LD || outfile_LE)
    {
        count++;
        if (std::getline(outfile_LD, line_LD) && std::getline(outfile_LE, line_LE)) {
            if (count < 17 + 2*139) {
                if (count < 8) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    double pedid_LE, lnlike_LE, log10like_LE;
                    outfile_LE >> pedid_LE >> lnlike_LE >> log10like_LE;
                    std::cout << log10like_LE << "\t";
                }
            } else {
                double pedid_LD, lnlike_LD, log10like_LD;
                outfile_LD >> pedid_LD >> lnlike_LD >> log10like_LD;
                std::cout << log10like_LD;
            }
        }
        std::cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to read two lines from two files and output them to another file?

Comment: I'm trying to read multiple lines from two files. Specifically, file1 and file2 has the same format (junk info from line 1-8 and 286-295, genetic info from line 9-285 and 296-537), I want to read line 9-285 from file 1 and 296-537 from file 2 and export these lines to column 1 (for file 1) and column 2 (for file2).

Comment: Are you sure that there are more than 295 lines in your second file?

Comment: I would simply just read the two files separately instead of trying to read them both at the same time. Will make your code easier to debug.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain that there are more than 295 lines in my second file. And yes, I'm starting to read the two files separately. Thank you so much for your prompt answer, ChrisD!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is in this line

```
if (std::getline(outfile_LD, line_LD) && std::getline(outfile_LE, line_LE))
```

When the first file is read through, it returns false. So the `&&` will return false and you get a lot of NL when the second file is processed. Try to use `||` op.

But I would read the first file and then the second file in different loops. On the other hand I think it the 1st block outfile_LD should be read, then outfile_LE. In your code it seems to be mixed.